# Paypal recurring subscription through silent url give invalid response?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Paypal recurring subscription through silent url give invalid response and blank status and subscription id on live account but this working on sandbox account fine.

```
string cmd = "_xclick-subscriptions";
        string redirect = "";        
        redirect += "?cmd=" + cmd;
        redirect += "&business=" + businessEmail;
        redirect += "&item_name=" + lblDesc.Text.Trim();        
        redirect += "&no_shipping=" + "2";
        redirect += "&no_note=" + "1";
        redirect += "&currency_code=" + "USD";
        redirect += "&lc=" + "";        
        redirect += "&return=" + successPage;
        redirect += "&cancel_return=" + FailurePage;
        redirect += "notify_url=" + successPage;
        redirect += "&rm=" + "2";
        //for first month free count=1
        redirect += "&a1=" + "0.0";
        redirect += "&p1=" + count.ToString();
        redirect += "&t1=" + "M";
        //new added parameter for recurring
        redirect += "&a3=" + total;
        redirect += "&p3=" + count.ToString();
        redirect += "&t3=" + "M";
        redirect += "&src=" + "1";
        redirect += "&sra=" + "1";      

        return "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"+ redirect;
```

get response by

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr&cmd=_notify-validate
```

Comment: Are you referring to when you get sent over to PayPal you are getting a blank page, or you are getting a blank page when you are redirected back to your site?

Comment: yes there are no values when i back from paypal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use PDT to get a response and then turn around and validate, make sure you have PDT enabled in your account and the return URL set up. Then try removing the lines of code for the return url and the rm variable that you are passing over.